# Inline Annotation prevents $modal from passing parameters to modal controller

Tags: angularjs

Live example see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0fUrh1NutiwoHXIu6BXR?p=preview).

For short, `$modal` here:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalCtrl',
  resolve: {
    value: function() { return value; }
  }
});
```

Below code can't get $scope.model.value set

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
    function($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
  $scope.model = {value : value};
  ...
```

But following code can

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
  $scope.model = {value : value};
  ...
```

That's weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

You must write all arguments inside the inline annotation:

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'value',
    function($scope, $modalInstance, value) {
```